# Integrating Swarm with Libgdx

Tags: android, integration, libgdx

Im looking to integrate Swarm high scores with my game that is built on a modified version of the game framework outlined in the Beginning Android Games book by Mario zechner.

The problem is that my game consists of two halves. One is the gameframework which contains the activity and all the background open gl code. That framework is added as a jar to my game. So i cant reference Swarm in the manifest of the framework, because it doesnt exist. The manifest of the game is the one that is used. Ive tried following the steps for getting Swarm working with libgdx but that doesnt work. I get a classnot found error on runtime.
anyone got any ideas?
thanks

**Edit**: Unable to post screenshot of the error as my rep is too low.But the error said:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instatiate activity ComponentInfo{com.MYSTUFF/com.MYSTUFF.FartJumper
```

Comment: Please post, at least, the exception message and the concerned class.

Comment: description of error added :D

Answer (score 1):

Class not found exceptions are thrown when a class loader is unable to find a class.  Check to make sure your classes are all named properly and referenced in the manifest xml file.

Comment: Hi,is strange, i double checked it all. but in the end i gave up and rewrote the game to use libgdx. Now all is good :D THanks tho!